# Leakage current through push-button and switch

Tags: stm32, battery-operated, power-consumption, leakage-current

I am developing a battery-powered application on a custom PCB, thus power consumption is critical. I am trying to minimize current consumption with stm32L4 MCU, by turning floating pins to analog, using power-saving modes etc, so far so good (total consumption reached ~40 uA in stop2 mode).

However, after soldering a push-button (connecting ground and reset (NRST) when pressed, in parallel with 100n cap) and a simple switch (for on-off, between battery and MCU) to PCB, I noticed that consumption has risen by another ~40-50 uA (during stop2 mode). Is that normal for such parts from your experience or I am missing something else? The referred button and switch are cheap usual parts, like [this](https://core-electronics.com.au/mini-push-button-switch.html) and [this](https://nz.rs-online.com/web/p/slide-switches/1543594/), nothing sort of sophisticated, and also has been soldered and desoldered 2-3 times (during testing), could that be the case ?

Here is the schematic for push-button (in PCB, the button is far away from MCU and oscillator, whereas capacitor is as close as seen here. I haven't put switch button in schematic yet, it connects/disconnects the battery with VDD pins [image]

To clarify, the whole circuit has many components that could be reason for the increased consumption. My question is if a simple push-button and/or a simple switch *per se* can "leak" current to ground (in terms of uA) , either because of overheating while soldering or just be being there.

Comment: Show the additions schematically.

Comment: Did you clean after soldering? It could be residue causing the conduction.

Comment: Was the capacitor already in the circuit, or did you add it too? Is it a ceramic SMD capacitor like X7R type? Is it possible you damaged the capacitor mechanically ot by heating it?

Comment: Can you take hi-res photos to share? And can you desolder one part at a time and see when the issue disappears?

Comment: @Justme the capacitor is ceraic SMD type, it was there before the addition of push-button. Overheating it while soldering is quite possible indeed

Comment: @Parker I did clean with a pcb/flu remover spray, will check again

Comment: Generally, my question is if - even with theoritically proper soldering - a push-button and a switch could add extra uAmps to the whole consumption, e.g. due to conduction

Comment: @p_a321 I would add a resistor between the switch and NRST. Currently you are shorting a capacitor and uC pin when you push the button. This could have caused damage to the uC pin causing the leak. It also could be the re-soldering multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, the cause of the consumption rise was plainly a floating pin elsewhere in the circuit. Switch and Push-button don't affect the consumption that dramatically ( although I found some switches getting burned after a resolder procedure, that caused them to have a remarkable voltage drop ). Residue cleaning and proper soldering will be considered more from now on, thanks everyone for the insights.